# Storing key using Keystore

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, password-protection

I am using keystore to protect private key in a file(with a password for that file).I did not understand this code

```
// save my secret key
javax.crypto.SecretKey mySecretKey;
KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry =
    new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(mySecretKey);
ks.setEntry("secretKeyAlias", skEntry, 
    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password));

// store away the keystore
java.io.FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream("newKeyStoreName");
    ks.store(fos, password);
} finally {
    if (fos != null) {
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

What is setEntry doing??
Are we saving private key through fileoutputstream ??If it is true where is the password for the file???
What is the extention of the file??Is it .jks??

Comment: Please answer to the comments..I am getting answers only to my quesitons(posted)not to my comments if any...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Java keystore is a container for cryptographic objects. It can contain symmetric keys, private keys and certificates. The [`setEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#setEntry%28java.lang.String,%20java.security.KeyStore.Entry,%20java.security.KeyStore.ProtectionParameter%29) method adds another entry to the keystore. In your case it adds a symmetric key identified by "secretKeyAlias" with protected by a password to the key store. If you wanted to save a private key, you should have created a `KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry` instead.

After you have created a keystore in memory, you can store it on the disk. The keystore has a [`store()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20char%5B%5D%29), which writes the keystore to a `Stream`. In this case a `FileOutputStream`. A [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) is also added to the keystore, protected by a password. In your case the password is the same as the one used above, but that is not necessary.

The usual extension for a Java keystore is .jks, but your code just stores it in a file named "newKeyStoreName".

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I have a doubt....In setEntry--- "skentry" is our entry(our input, may be any type of key)and 3rd parameter is the password for the file where "skentry" is stored.Is is right??Please clarify....

Comment: @user1168647: Yes, the second parameter is the entry - in your case it should be a PrivateKeyEntry. The third parameter specifies how the entry should be protected. If you specify PasswordProtection, it will be encrypted with a password. The file itself is not encrypted (only MACced), but each individual entry can be encrypted under a password.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rasmus Faber,But i was stuck here,ks.setEntry("d1",prvate,new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(pass)); d1-->is the alias,prvate-->KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry prvate=new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(pr,null)(pr is private key from keypair generator); I am getting null pointer exception because 2nd parameter should be chain(an array of certificates) but i am not using any certificates in my code...What is the solution...

Comment: @user1168647: I am sorry, but I do not believe that you can store a private key without a certificate in a Java keystore. I do not know the reason behind this restriction. You might want to ask another question about the best solution, but I would say that your options is a) Use another storage mechanism b) create a self-signed certificate to store with the private key.